# Jmeter listeners for capturing sql queries

Tags: sql, jdbc, jmeter

I have not found how it is possible to catch sql queries through a test case created from a user.

I want to see the sql queries executed in the background when I press the execution button for a recorded test case in Jmeter.

I have not found any listener capturing sql in JMeter.

The only thing I found, is [creating a JDBC connection and a JDBC request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-db-test-plan.html)

Which means providing to JMeter the database information in order to connect the JMeter to the database and afterwards sending custom sql queries to this database to catch the results, but this is something different from what I want.

Is somehow possible to catch the sql queries(maybe there is a listener) created from me when I ran through my application a function which searches for data?

Comment: Did my answer helped? Did you find other solution?

Answer (score 0):

`View Results Tree` Listener Show all Samplers including `JDBC request`, In `View Results Tree` Click `Configure` button and check `Save Sampler Data(XML)` (Save as XML also should be checked).

If you save it to log file (Filename field) you can view SQL in samplerData tag,

Log file created includes:

```
<sample t="2" it="0" lt="1" ct="0" ts="1498028083895" s="true" lb="JDBC  rc="200" rm="OK" tn="name" dt="text" de="UTF-8" by="9" sby="0" sc="1" ec="0" ng="1" na="1" hn="name">
  <responseHeader class="java.lang.String">615492551, URL=jdbc:oracle:... Oracle JDBC driver</responseHeader>
  <requestHeader class="java.lang.String"></requestHeader>
  <responseData class="java.lang.String">1 updates</responseData>
  <responseFile class="java.lang.String"></responseFile>
  <samplerData class="java.lang.String">[Update Statement] update table1 set a='b' 

</samplerData>
</sample>
```

Comment: Thanks for clarification. Despite the fact that i managed to capture my logs I still can not find the samplerData. Maybe i have to search more thoroughly.

Comment: In `View Results Tree` Click Configure and check `Save Sampler Data(XML)`